# Equivalent ndb attribute for _model_class attribute of db queries

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, app-engine-ndb

Is there a way to get the model class related to an ndb query?

The `kind` attribute is only a string. `db` queries have a `_model_class` attribute, but I am unable to find an equivalent for `ndb`.

Comment: There doesn't appear to be one, went poking around inside the query instance and could not find anything.  You may want to create an explicit registry of kind to class mapping, or use getattr on the module containing your models.